# "doubled POM" error when running m2e in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

We recently experience the problem that POMs in the local repository are broken in a special way: The content of the POM appears twice, or, in some cases, just some end part of the POM appears twice. So these POMs look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
</project>
  ...
</project>
```

Obviously, these POMs cannot be read correctly.

One case in which the problem appears often is the following workflow:

1. Remove the local repository
2. Start Eclipse with an existing workspace
3. (Immediately) start a build inside Eclipse.

My guess is that m2e does not properly handle concurrency. The automatic download of dependencies in the background and the build try to download the same POMs at roughly the same time.

Is my analysis correct?

If so, can I do anything about it?

If not, what is the explanation?

EDIT

It seems that the error also occurs if one only starts Eclipse with a lot of projects in the workspace (without starting a in-Eclipse build).

Comment: Looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6281, but it is very hard to reproduce. If there are more hints, we can try to fix it.

Comment: There might also be a connection to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534228